# SMOTE error - Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series dtype mappings

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, imblearn, smote

I am using SMOTE because my data set is imbalanced, but I am getting the error message as stated below. I have seen a previous post in this forum on the same topic. However, in that post, it is suggested that it is due to duplicate column names that this error happens. I have checked my dataset and there are no duplicate column names, but still I am getting this error. My dataset has categorical variables and all have been converted into 1's and 0's.

```
sm = SMOTE(random_state = 2) 
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

Here is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-9ac314f8e551> in <module>
  1 sm = SMOTE(random_state = 2)
 ----> 2 X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\base.py in fit_resample(self, X, y)
    86               if binarize_y else output[1])
    87 
---> 88         X_, y_ = arrays_transformer.transform(output[0], y_)
    89         return (X_, y_) if len(output) == 2 else (X_, y_, output[2])
    90 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in transform(self, X, y)
     38 
     39     def transform(self, X, y):
---> 40         X = self._transfrom_one(X, self.x_props)
     41         y = self._transfrom_one(y, self.y_props)
     42         return X, y

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils\_validation.py in
_transfrom_one(self, array, props)
     57             import pandas as pd
     58             ret = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=props["columns"])
---> 59             ret = ret.astype(props["dtypes"])
     60         elif type_ == "series":
     61             import pandas as pd

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)    5681                 if col_name in dtype:    5682                     results.append(
-> 5683                         col.astype(dtype=dtype[col_name], copy=copy, errors=errors)    5684                     )    5685        else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)    5664             if self.ndim == 1:  # i.e. Series    5665                 if len(dtype) > 1 or self.name not in dtype:
-> 5666                     raise KeyError(    5667                         "Only the Series name can be used for "    5668                        "the key in Series dtype mappings."

KeyError: 'Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series dtype mappings.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error with the following - you may or may not use ravel().

sm = SMOTE(random_state = 2)
X_train_res, y_train_res = sm.fit_resample(X_train.values, y_train.ravel())